# Clickable tiles in ASP.NET Core MVC using Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC website. As a part of it I want to show some Tiles(like tiles on a mobile) at the initial load. Each tile should be clickable which will launch another website (maybe StackOverflow website).

I did a bit of digging and found that it can be done by using Bootstrap or css/html.

Is Bootstrap the best way to achieve it? Are there any code samples?

I am new to Bootstrap, so I do not have any code to add in yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples may fit your needs:

- You can use [CSS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid) to custom your row, column or image **style** to manage the format.

To click the image and navigate to website, you can **add the image tag inside  tag**, following is a demo:

```
<body style="background-color:darkgray;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <div>
            <a href="https://www.google.com/">
                <img src="~/Images/dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" style="margin-top: 5px; width: 100px; height: 100px; "/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67444934/clickable-tiles-in-asp-net-core-mvc-using-bootstrap">
                <img src="~/Images/leaf.jpg" class="img-thumbnail"  style="margin-top: 5px; width: 100px; height: 100px; "/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <div>
            <a href="https://www.google.com/">
                <img src="~/Images/sun.png" class="img-thumbnail" style="margin-top: 5px; width: 100px; height: 200px; margin-left: 5px;"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

And you can also refer to these links: [grid tutorial](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) and [image grid sample](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_grid_responsive.asp)

Or you want something like [**carousel**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)?